# Time complexity of operators

Tags: operators, big-o, time-complexity

What is the time complexity with big-o notation of logics operators like OR, AND, NOT ?
Can they be expressed with this notation ?

**Example :**

```
100111001 OR 10111100001
1011000 AND 111111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripple-carry mechanics aside (which are only noticeable if your cpu is built in let's say minecraft), you can consider those operations O(1).

Edit: This is of course the case for when the amount of bytes per operand doesn't exceed what the platform can stuff in one operation. If your input is let's say 17 bits for each operand, then a CPU that can only do 16-bit operations maximum can't perform this action with 1 operation. I suppose with the amount of times the operation is required to be performed as the letter "n", the big-o notation would be O(n) in that case.